# Radial tree layout for cytoscape.js?

Tags: javascript, graph-theory, cytoscape.js

I tried to achieve a radial tree layout using the `concentric` layout of cytoscape.js. The resulting layout should look similar to the *radial tidy tree* for d3js (https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-radial-tidy-tree).

The graph is directed, has ~1800 edges  and ~1500 nodes of which 9 are root nodes. The nodes are distributed to 12 levels. Most nodes belong to one of 4 levels, the other levels rarely have nodes. The edges from a node always target nodes on lower levels but a node can have edges to nodes on different levels.

The `concentric` layout seems not to be suitable. Is there any other layout for cytoscape.js for radial tree layouts?

Comment: Can you please specify why the concentric layout is not suitable? THX

Comment: 1. The concentric layout  always creates a big distance between the nodes with lower levels and the nodes with higher level 

2. The nodes are not clustered in that way that the subordinate nodes are more or less in the same segment of the circle, they are sometimes too much distributed or in other segments, causing many crossovers of the edges.

Maybe I am using the  concentric layout not properly, but my impression is that these are features which are inherent to the concentric layout.

Here is an example of my graph: http://jsfiddle.net/hqs2j4aL/9/

Comment: Ahh ok, the problem is, that the cytoscape desktop version does that (you can place each and every node in the canvas and it will probably look good), cytoscape.js doesn‘t really have that functionality. If you have a set dataSource, you can place each node and export it to cy.js.... with changing data you will have a bad time i think :[

Comment: Placing > 1500 nodes manually does not sound like a suitable solution to me. Anyway, thanks for your answer. So there is neither a layout in cy.js nor an extension to it which allows laying out graph as radial tree? Since cy.js has focus on molecular biology I expected it to also be supportive for biological classification threes. Except of lacking a radial tree layout, it is in principle perfectly suitable for biodiversity data.

Comment: I strongly agree with you, but as much as i would wish for a layout like that, i know from first hand how hard it is to code a complex and flexible layout for cytoscape. Can you use d3.js for your project?

Comment: Yes, d3.js is exactly what I will be using now. THX.